# Odoo 13: act_window action in code ignores search_view

Tags: python, odoo

I've got a smart button which should open a specific view with a specific search_view.
I created an action in xml for the smart button with view_id and search_view_id:

```
<button class="oe_stat_button" type="action" name="%(action_expert_positions)d" icon="fa-list-ol">
  <field string="Positions" name="positions_count" widget="statinfo"/>
</button>

<record id="action_expert_positions" model="ir.actions.act_window">
  <field name="name">Positions</field>
  <field name="res_model">expert.position</field>
  <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
  <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
  <field name="view_id" ref="project_expert_position_tree"/>
  <field name="domain">[("project_id", "=", active_id)]</field>
  <field name="search_view_id" ref="project_expert_position_tree_search"/>
  <field name="context">{'default_project_id': active_id, 'search_default_project_phase_closed': 1}</field>
</record>
```

This works very well. It shows the specific view and also the search view with specific filter.

Now the filter (search_default_...) should be activated dynamically depending on a field in of parent object.
For this I changed the smart button and the xml-action to a function which creates the action so that I can add the dynamic later:

```
<button class="oe_stat_button" type="object" name="get_positions" icon="fa-list-ol">
  <field string="Positions" name="positions_count" widget="statinfo"/>
</button>

def get_positions(self):
  self.ensure_one()
  return {
    'name': 'Positions',
    'res_model': 'expert.position',
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
    'view_mode': 'tree',
    'view_id': self.env.ref('my_project.project_expert_position_tree').id,
    'domain': [('project_id', '=', self.id)],
    'search_view_id': self.env.ref('my_project.project_expert_position_tree_search').id,
    'context': "{'default_project_id': active_id, 'search_default_project_phase_closed': 1}"
  }
```

Now the view is correct but the search_view is not the specific, it is the default search_view.
I've debugged the function and can confirm that the id of the search view is added correctly in the returned json.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Shouldn't the context be a dictionary instead of a string?

Comment: @Eric:  
  
Thanks for the tip.  
I've changed it but the search_view is still ignored.  
  
before: `'context': "{'default_project_id': active_id, 'search_default_project_phase_closed': 1}"`  
after: `'context': {'default_project_id': self.id, 'search_default_project_phase_closed': 1}`  
  
I think both versions are working because in both versions the default_project_id is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for that in my github post:

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/66147

'search_view_id': (self.env.ref('my_project.project_expert_position_tree_search').id, ),

The doc says "(id, name) pair, id is the database identifier of a specific search view to load"
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/actions.html#window-actions-ir-actions-act-window

Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Impacted versions: 13.0

Steps to reproduce: see below the second code block

Current behavior: specified search_view is ignored when using the function to generate action

Expected behavior: specified search view should be used

Description:

I've got a smart button which should open a specific view with a specific search_view. I created an action in xml for the smart button with view_id and search_view_id:

```
<button class="oe_stat_button" type="action" name="%(action_expert_positions)d" icon="fa-list-ol">
  <field string="Positions" name="positions_count" widget="statinfo"/>
</button>

<record id="action_expert_positions" model="ir.actions.act_window">
  <field name="name">Positions</field>
  <field name="res_model">expert.position</field>
  <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
  <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
  <field name="view_id" ref="project_expert_position_tree"/>
  <field name="domain">[("project_id", "=", active_id)]</field>
  <field name="search_view_id" ref="project_expert_position_tree_search"/>
  <field name="context">{'default_project_id': active_id, 'search_default_project_phase_closed': 1}</field>
</record>
```

This works very well. It shows the specific view and also the search view with a specific filter.

Now the filter (search_default_...) should be activated dynamically depending on a field in of parent object. For this I changed the smart button and the xml-action to a function which creates the action so that I can add the dynamic later:

```
<button class="oe_stat_button" type="object" name="get_positions" icon="fa-list-ol">
  <field string="Positions" name="positions_count" widget="statinfo"/>
</button>

def get_positions(self):
  self.ensure_one()
  return {
    'name': 'Positions',
    'res_model': 'expert.position',
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
    'view_mode': 'tree,form',
    'view_ids': [self.env.ref('my_project.project_expert_position_tree').id, self.env.ref('my_project.expert_position_form').id],
    'domain': [('project_id', '=', self.id)],
    'search_view_id': self.env.ref('my_project.project_expert_position_tree_search').id,
    'context': {'default_project_id': self.id, 'search_default_project_phase_closed': 1}
  }
```

you can see :
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/66147